# Excluding a subdirectory from a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns, subdirectory

I have the domain example.com, this goes to my wordpress site.
I want to create the subfolder "tech" within it, ie example.com/tech/.
However, with this subfolder, I don't want Wordpress treating it like it's part of wordpress. In a way, I want wordpress to ignore this folder, and instead for the browser to direct to whatever functions and files I place inside the folder.

My server is running Nginx. A way to set this up within Wordpress would be optimal, within Nginx would be runner-up, DNS configuration modifications would be a last resort. The goal here being that I would like example.com/tech/ to be example.com/tech/. I could easily make another domain point to this folder and run out of it, but I want it to use the domain that the Wordpress site uses.

Answer (score 0):

DNS has no concept of a path. Once you get past "example.com", DNS is no longer a potential solution.

However, one possible option would be to create "tech.example.com" in DNS, point it at the same IP as your normal Wordpress site, and then you've got options to handle the request differently based on the HTTP header or virtual hosts config.